# How to Accelerate MultioutputClassifier that contains Xgboost? (python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have following piece of code, i want to accelerate MultioutputClassifier, i tried to write n_jobs = -1 for MultioutputClassifier but it becames slower, i tried n_jobs = -1 for Xgboost but nothing changed. TREE_METHOD = 'gpu_hist' parameter couldnt change the time too.

```
model = MultiOutputClassifier(
        xgb.XGBClassifier(objective="binary:logistic",
                          colsample_bytree = 0.5,
                          gamma = 0.1,
                          learning_rate = 0.1,
                          max_depth = 20,
                          min_child_weight = 3,
                          estimators= 100,
                          reg_lambda=5.0,
                          subsample=0.7
                         ))
```

Any idea about how to accelerate this? Are there any parameter that i can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do some distributed learning with Dask, as described [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/dask.html).
Apart from that, there are some [suggestions](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters-Tuning.html#for-faster-speed) on how to increase the speed of training done by LightGBM (which is a very similar algorithm) such as:

- Grow Shallower Trees (e.g. by decreasing `max_depth`)
- Grow Less Trees (e.g. by introducing `early_stopping`)
- Use Less Data (e.g. by `bagging`, you can also look for more `colsample_` parameters)